# Import existing data into core data

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I built Xcode project with core data I also worked on entities and create dozens. Now I want to import existing data and it has too large I just saw [RayWanderLich Tut](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated) and what it describe the method, it take too much time. I know that it create sqlite file in share directory which is show message of encryption when you try to open this. I also have idea it create tables on base of entities by using this line "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1" in edit scheme. So my question are following.

- It really create sqlite file which is accessible for developer.
- If yes we can access then are we able to dump data?
- If No, then kindly guide me any other fast solution for this because I have thousands of records which need to initially?

I am looking for your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With that tutorial you can create an SQLite file which you embed into the app and use as the initial data (it is your core data model, full of data) that the user can then modify. For the app, this is the absolute fastest option because it doesn't need to do any import. All it does is move the file from the bundle to the documents (or other suitable folder).

The SQLite file that is created for you to embed isn't special and can be accessed just like any other SQLite file (using appropriate tools to open and interrogate the contents).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I embed into app as initial data?

Comment: Just like you do with images. When app launches (before you setup the Core Data stack, check if you need to and copy to where you want the file to be).

Comment: Don't you think so it will be use as like normal sqlite file, then what will be advantage of Core data? And also I am getting confuse how to relate tables and entity between core data and sqlite file? Thanks again :)

Comment: Don't try to relate. Either use SQLite directly, or use Core Data and (basically) forget that it uses SQLite internally. Core Data adds functionality and abstraction - it makes life easier.

Comment: I know that core data use sqlite but that is encrypted. Actually I confusing around that are you suggesting me to use sqlite directly without the help or without using core data function for adding deleting and etc. If yes then what is purpose of core data for having entities? Kindly if you are getting frustrating for guiding me too long, Kindly refer me any tutorial of what you are suggesting for saving time?

Comment: The SQLite file isn't encrypted unless you actively did something to encrypt it. I am not suggesting you use SQLite directly, I simply said that you could if you want to investigate the file (I wouldn't).

Comment: Thanks but I didn't get the method you are suggesting, I mean how to accomplish this. Thanks again